# How can I load Hive table with complex data types using INSERT-SELECT query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

We have a query for loading the data into a table using a `INSERT-SELECT` query directly on another table(s) as shown below

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE <table1>
SELECT * FROM <table2> t2
WHERE <some-conditions>;
```

**Similarly how can load a table with complex data types? How can I let couple of/some of columns in my SELECT query contribute for a complex data typed column? Am i clear?**

Schema of the table1 is

```
TABLE (col1 INT, col2 STRING, col3 ARRAY<STRING>)
```

**Note:** Loading from a file to such tables is possible, but I just wanna try whether I can load using above `INSERT-SELECT` query fashion. Appreciate your interest.

Comment: what is the schema of the table where the data is coming from? e.g. t2 in your example? does it match the schema of the table being loaded, can it be converted/casted?

Comment: Going one by one of your questions, Schema given above is for table1 only. Now I may get the data as a text file to be loaded into table1, which is very well possible and feasible as well. **If I have a simple SELECT query or a JOIN query which takes couple of columns from table2 (or from couple of tables using JOIN) in order to load the data into tabel1, how can i make sure that the data being pulled suits the schema?** Am I clear? Thats where I need the syntax of the `INSERT-SELECT` query.

Comment: **how can i make sure that the data being pulled suits the schema?** -- if you know the destination schema, then you can chose what to select and convert if necessary to new schema -- using `CAST` of UDFs which generate new types of data, e.g. `SPLIT` will create array<string> from string.

Comment: Can i have any example for using `SPLIT`?

Answer (score 1):

The Hive equivalent of  insert .. select is  one of:

```
1. from (table 2 query)
insert [overwrite] table <table1> [partition clause if partitioned table]
```

OR

```
2. create table table1 as select <table2 query>
```

Note  the #2 (CTAS) is not reliable. You would be better served by doing #1 in conjunction with either an explicit table creation or something like:

```
create table <table1> **like** table2
```